# Mysql search for entries that have turkish characters

Tags: php, mysql, turkish

I've seen Horde's address book application that delivers matches very nicely for searches that do not have the correct characters. 
For example if searching for 'Garcon' the entry with 'Garçon' is delivered. Or a search for 'Tugla' does also deliver 'Tuğla'. 
I wonder if this is own code or can Mysql handle this. If yes, how can this be achieved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting the collation to the appropriate setting (in your case, probably `uft8_turkish_ci`) will affect which characters are considered equal. I'm fairly sure that with that collation Turkish characters will be equal to their equivalents, but I haven't had much experience in testing this fact - just going by what I read on the MySQL manual site.

Comment: I've checked the collation of the Horde-DB, this is utf8_general_ci. Could you point me to the Mysql documentation where the matches of equivalents is described?

Comment: Yes, the equivalent characters are handled by the collation-table. Thanks